# Как преобразовать html коды в символы?

Tags: php

Есть строка, например:

```
$str = "What&#39;s happening";
```

Мне же нужно чтобы она была выведена как:

> What's happening

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А где эта строка есть?

Comment: @Эникейщик в переменной например

Comment: А как она туда попала? Из БД или откуда?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в ответе от  API

Comment: Это можно загуглить например по таким ключевым словам "php html decode"; Гугл наверняка предложит php.net/html_entity_decode; Если вы её попробуете, то убедитесь, что она не работает; Но не спешите закрывать php.net, загляните в комментарии на странице этой функции.

Comment: Хотя можно и просто html_entity_decode. Для одинарной кавычки нужен дополнительный флаг ENT_QUOTES. Официальная документация -- прекрасный источник знаний.

Answer (score -1):

Вот так?

```
<p>
  <?php
    echo $str;
  ?>
</p>
```